# How to use Intent constructor?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

In android,Is there any differences between the following code?

1. new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
2. new Intent(Context.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
3. new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyOtherActivity.class);

Please explain in details.example code also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *should* read [documentation and guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  1> new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class); here this means the context of your current   
    activity
  3> new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyOtherActivity.class); here getApplicationContext() means the context of your application.
```

Comment: ok when i use this,context or application context.

Comment: for long running process like service , use application context